# Замена ?id в URL [WORDPRESS]

Tags: wordpress, url

Всем привет. Помогите разобраться в проблеме. CMS : WordPress
Имеется страница **www.mysite.ru/reviews/** , в ней обработчик на $_GET запрос. Т.е. когда вводишь **www.mysite.ru/reviews/?id=215** , открывается отзыв под номером 215. Мне нужно сделать в хорошем виде URL.. Что-то вроде **www.mysite.ru/reviews/215**
Пробовал через различные настройки .htaccess - не получается, выбивает 404..

Answer (score 0):

В настройках "Постоянные ссылки" настраивается чпу, если правильно понял

Comment: Да, но не только когда обработка написана прям в коде.. В общем ответа так не нашел, но написал костыль. Вопрос еще актуален..